# Single user mode boot stuck

Tags: ubuntu, boot, root

I have an old Ubuntu box with an unknown root password. It boots fine in regular mode, but it gets stuck when booting to single user mode:

[image: Stuck single user mode boot]

For searchability, the last few lines are:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[5.525592] Adding 10803676k swap on /dev/sda5. Priority: -1 extents:1 across:10803676k
```

It's using a kernel at this level:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, kernel 3.2.0-69-generic
```

I've tried both selecting the (recovery) option in grub, which appends ro single to the kernel line, and adding single to the usual kernel line. Either way, it gets stuck in this screen.

When booting normally, it boots into X and lets me log in as a non-root user.

How do I get single user mode boot to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from live CD or flash drive and reset root password
Make sure all file systems are healthy. Use sudo if you can from the current user.
Inspect which services run in which run levels. Maybe something got switched off for init 1.